# Best way to prevent extension from running based on list of URLs and notify too?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I understand how to include something like this in a manifest :

```
"exclude_matches" : ["*://somesite.somewhere.com/*"],
```

But, this doesn't seem useful for many URLs.

Is there a way to check an external file to see if the URL or pattern exists?

Could I display a notification when the URL or pattern exists to remind the user that the extension is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New solution, taking into account OP's requirements for:

1. A URL list not modifiable by the users.
2. A URL list that can be updated centrally and take effect immediately.

Since you can't bind the "exclude_matches" attribute to an external file, you can achieve what you want through AJAX and **[Programmatic Injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)**:

1. Register an appropriate listener in your background-page (or yet better event-page) with **[chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)**
2. When a tab's location is updated, have your background- or event-page fetch a URL list though an AJAX request to your server and decide whether a content script should be injected or not. (As per your exact requirements, you could have your background-page fetch the updated file periodically and not asking for it at every tab-update for better performance.)
3. Finally, use **[chrome.tabs.executeScript()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)** to inject your scripts into the web-page (if necessary).

Take a look **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)** to get started with AJAX.

And finally, some demo, working code to play with:

In **manifest.json**:

```
...
// 1. Ask permission to listen for changes in tabs
// 2. Ask permission to "interfere" with any web-page 
// (using the "http" or "https" schemes - modify appropriately for other schemes)
"permissions": {
    ...
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
},
...
// Include the file with the URLs and/or patterns to check
// in your background- or event-page.
"background": {
    "persistent": false,   // <-- Recommended, but optional
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
...
```

In **content_script.js**:

```
// Do stuff...
alert("I've been injected !\nHow cool is that !");
```

In **background.js**:

```
var ajaxURL = "http://url.to.your/server";

// Asynchronously fetch the list of excluded URLs
// (use synchronous calls if it better suits your purpose)
function getExcludedURLs(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {   // <-- the request has completed
            if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                successCallback(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            } else {
                failureCallback(ajaxRequest.statusText);
            }
        }
    });
    // Send an HTTP GET request and get the response asynchronously
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

// A function to be called on AJAX request failure:
//   alerts the user regarding the failure
function onAJAXFailure(statusText) {
    alert("Unable to fetch the excluded URLs list :(\n"
          + "Error: " + statusText);
}

// Retuns a function to be called on AJAX request success:
//   test if the URL is in the list and injects the content script
// If you feel like delving into some more advanced concepts, 
// look for "Closures in JS", e.g.: 
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures
function onAJAXSuccess(tab) {
    return function(responseText) {
        var excludedURLsArray = JSON.parse(responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < excludedURLsArray.length; i++) {
            // Look for an exact match with an excluded URL
            // (modify according to your needs - e.g. check host only, etc)
            if (tab.url == excludedURLsArray[i]) {
                // No injection - inform user and return
                alert("Extension not available on '" + tab.url + "'.\n"
                      + "You are on your own !");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Ending up here means we must inject...
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "content_script.js",
            "allFrames": false   // <-- or whatever suits you
        });
    };
}

// Add a listener for the "onUpdated" event
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status && (info.status == "complete")) {
        getExcludedURLs(onAJAXSuccess(tab), onAJAXFailure);
    }
});
```

On the server-side, you'll need a way to send back a JSON encoded array of excluded URLs. There are numerous ways to do it (depending on the server-side technologies used). Here is just a sample implementation in PHP (for the sake of completeness).

At **http://url.to.your/server**:

```
<?php
$excludedURLs = array(
    "http://stackoverflow.com/",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com/",
    "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension",
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension"
);

echo(json_encode($excludedURLs));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: @ExpertSystems No joy. The AJAX doesn't seem to work. For example, no error is thrown when the php fie is not available. The "You are on your own !" alert does not fire (probably same reason). Finally, the content.js alert fires many times (sometimes 40+). Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I tested it mtself before posting and it works fine for me. It is not meant as production-ready solution though, jyst as a sketchy draft to get you started. You might want to enhance it, capturing and handling more events for example. It definitely shouldn't fire more than once for each tab-update, but (as always) you have to figure out what (in your particular setup) causes the problem, in order to fix it :)

Comment: @ExpertSystems Thanks for the note. I do think the problem is with the AJAX call not firing. How can we check that as a first step. The php file returns is there and returns the data. But, if I remove it from the server I don't even get your error message. I suspect that nothing will work without a successful AJAX call.

Comment: @user1452893: I really don't know why it not working for you. I test it with a non-existent target URL and the `failureCallback` is executed normally (of course there is not response, since the URL does not exist). I suspect you are not using the exact code I gave above, so I cannot help debug some code I cannot see. Please, post a **[SSCCE](http://ssccee.org)** demonstrating the problem (i.e. call to non-existing URL and failureCallbac not being fired).

Comment: @ExpertSystems Thanks. I will start completely fresh with the code you furnished. Nothing has to be added anywhere, right? That includes the manifest?  For example, var ajaxURL = "http://url.to.your/server" should throw an error.

Comment: @user1452893: You just need to add the required fields in `manifest.json` (name, version etc).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40004/discussion-between-user1452893-and-expertsystem)

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind the "exclude_matches" attribute to an external file.

If you need to check a file containing URLs or patterns, I would suggest using **[Programmatic Injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)**:

1. Register an appropriate listener in your background-page (or yet better event-page), e.g.
   **[chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)**
2. When a tab's location is updated, have your background- or event-page check a bundled js file containing URLs/patterns and decide whether a content script should be injected or not.
3. Finally, use **[chrome.tabs.executeScript()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)** to inject your scripts into the web-page (if necessary).

As per request, some *untested* code to get you started:

In **manifest.json**:

```
...
// 1. Ask permission to listen for changes in tabs
// 2. Ask permission to "interfere" with any web-page 
// (using the "http" or "https" schemes - modify appropriately for other schemes)
"permissions": {
    ...
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
},
...
// Include the file with the URLs and/or patterns to check
// in your background- or event-page.
"background": {
    "persistent": false,   // <-- Recommended, but optional
    "scripts": [
        "background.js",
        "lotsOfURLsAndOrPatterns.js"
    ]
},
...
```

In **lotsOfURLsAndOrPatterns.js**:

```
...
// E.g.:
var excludedURLsArray = [
    "<1st url...>",
    "<2nd url...>",
    ...
];
...
```

In **background.js**:

```
// Add a listener for the "onUpdated" event
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.url) {
        // The URL has changed - you can device other methods for checking
        // if you need to inject the tab, according to your particular setup
        for (var i = 0; i < excludedURLsArray.length; i++) {
            // Look for an exact match with an excluded URL
            // (modify according to your needs - e.g. check host only, etc)
            if (info.url == excludedURLsArray[i]) {
                // No injection - inform user and return
                alert("Extension not available on '" + info.url + "'.\n"
                      + "You are on your own !");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Ending up here means we must inject...
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            "file": "myContentScript.js",
            "allFrames": false   // <-- or whatever suits you
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @user1452893: Added some *untested* sample code. Feel free to come back, should you have any questions or face any problems implementing it. Also, please, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you solve your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for going the extra mile! This is a great help. Will begin work this evening.

Comment: I cannot get the lotsOfURLsAndOrPatterns.js to reside in an external location so it's not useful if I need to update the CRX every time a url is added or deleted. :(

Comment: @user1452893: Sorry, I did not realize this was a requirement. I can propose two solutions: 1. Use chrome.storage or localStorage to store the list of URLs and implement a page (within your extension) for modifying them. 2. If it is for personal use you can edit the lotsOfURLsOrPatterns.js with any editor. E.g. in Windows: "<USERHOME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\<ExtensionID>\<Version>\lotsOfURLsOrPatterns.js" (Since it is a long path, you would create a shortcut to it and just double-click to edit.)

Comment: @ExpertSystems Thanks for the note. 1) Would expose and maybe give control of the "blacklist" to the user which is not viable. 2) Not personal use. I do have experience with localStorage and Chrome's version but see no path to apply to serve while avoiding CRX updates every time a revision is made. Thanks as always for your help. The only thing I can think of is maybe an AJAX call to an external JSON file to check but above my pay grade to code that.

Comment: @user1452893: If you want your users to not have "access" to the URL list, then indeed it should not reside localy. So, your only option would be to host the file on z server and fetch through an AJAX call (as you mentioned). BTW, that is not that difficult to implement. I would suggest giving it a try (as long as you are willing and have the resources to operate a server for hosting the file).

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yes, I have the server and am willing but don't really know where to start on that approach.

Comment: @user1452893: Since your actual requrements turned out to be quite different from what I had in mind originally, I added a new answer that will (hopefully) get you started with AJAX. (It is kind of lengthy, though, so don't be hasty, or you might miss some important detail :D)